# Get Elements from one XElement that are not in another XElement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I load two XElements from two different files. One is a default file and the other is the live XML. Basically I need to know how to compare the two XElements and get a collection of all Elements that are in the live file and not in the defaultfile.

I don't care about checking for values I only care if there is an element in the live file that isn't in the default file.

Basically I am comparing two Web.config files and when a user is upgrading our product I need to check their web.config to find any element they have added that isn't in our template and add them to our template before I lay it down and overwrite theirs.

Comment: For each element, do you need to compare complete contents, or is there something like an ID field you could use? (Sample XML would make this question easier to answer.)

Comment: No there is no ID field it is two IIS web.config files and I just need to find elements that a client may have added to their web.config that we don't ship with our product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var addedNames = new HashSet<string>(
    liveXml.Elements().Select(e => e.Name).Except(
        defXml.Elements().Select(e => e.Name)
    )
);
var addedElements = liveXml
    .Elements()
    .Where(e => addedNames.Contains(e.Name))
    .ToList();
```

This approach constructs a list of `liveXml`'s element names that are not present in `defXml`, puts them in a set, and then uses that set to filter `liveXml`'s elements.

For removed elements, reverse the order of operand that you pass to `Except`, and filter `defXml`:

```
var droppedNames = new HashSet<string>(
    defXml.Elements().Select(e => e.Name).Except(
        liveXml.Elements().Select(e => e.Name)
    )
);
var droppedElements = defXml
    .Elements()
    .Where(e => addedNames.Contains(e.Name))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This worked great thank you very much. All I need to do now is get this to search the child elements for each of the elements and it will be perfect. Thanks again.